# How to get Chrome Performance lighthouse data using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, lighthouse

is there any java API to capture Chrome Performance Lighthouse data using selenium Java?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not your answer but you can try something like this;

For example this calculates Scroll performance of in browser;

```
public static String toLastElement(WebDriver driver, List<WebElement> webElementList) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        int y = webElementList.get(webElementList.size() - 1).getLocation().getY();
        return (String) js.executeScript("var start = performance.now(); " +
                            "window.scrollTo(0," + y + "); " +
                            "var end = performance.now(); " +
                            "return '' + (end - start) + '';");
    }
```

In summary you can use javascript to measure performance in Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: And also please check; https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/

Comment: I used the same thing. but i want the performance audit data coz, it contains recommendations for each elements that can be optimized. it can be done using NODE js, using : { npm install -g lighthouse
lighthouse --output=json --output-path=./report.json https://airhorner.com/ } this snippet.

Comment: here comes another problem, i have created a runable jar that can be used in any selenium automation script to capture all the performance needed with the redirection of pages. Now if i call light house command from jar it will find those values, but there is a high chance that user might not have node installed.